# LinkedIn - how to pass query parameter

Tags: java, oauth, playframework, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

is there anyway to pass query parameter through linked log in process.
I am trying to add query parameter but linked in remove it and return only state and code parameters.
is there anyway i can do this?

Comment: What's the parameter you want to pass?

Comment: token Id. that i send by email to a user. and the user opens login page with that parameter and i want to keep it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using just "state" parameter for this. You can put there anything you want.

Comment: thanks Tomek, i read in linkedin documentation that state is used for security purpose!

Comment: Yes, exactly. Just encode your object in some way to make it quite unique.